Why are the layers of the James Webb Telescope’s sunshield so thin?
The Webb telescope has a 5-layer sunshield, the thickest of which is 0.05 millimeters thick, and others are even thinner. I can not understand why it has to be extremely thin.
this answer to Why was creating sunshields for Webb telescope challenging? in Astronomy SE links to the NASA websiteAbout Webb's Sunshield, which says:

Each layer of the sunshield is incredibly thin. Layer 1 faces the sun and is only 0.05 millimeters (0.002 inches) thick, while the other four layers are 0.025 mm (0.001 inches). The thickness of the aluminum and silicon coatings are even smaller. The silicon coating is ~50 nanometers (nm) (1.9 microinches) thick, while the aluminum coating is ~100 nm (3.93 microinches) thick.

Maybe I have a wrong assumption that leads to this question, my assumption is that maintaining a very thin film is difficult, and it might be easily damaged; a thicker one can be more resistant. Is this wrong?

Well, they aren’t too thin for the application, but just right (or maybe even thicker than needed). Related: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/59146/why-was-creating-sunshields-for-webb-telescope-challenging

@JonCuster Actually the linked question is also mine. I asked that there, but someone suggested to ask it her in this community as it is more related to space vehicles than astronomy.

The answer you accepted and the comments there answer this question.

@JonCuster Is it all about occupying less volume when folding?

See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Webb_Space_Telescope_sunshield

I suspect it's more mass than volume; my napkin math is that there must be about 40 kilos of Kapton in the sunshield, not counting any of the structural members or moving parts. That's not a lot, but if you (say) doubled the thickness, that 40 kilos has to come out of some other part of the spacecraft.

@JonCuster JamesK's answer seems to "shoot from the hip" there, so I suggested the OP ask here to get a well-reasoned, authoritatively supposed answer. Was it ultimately weight (doubtful) or packing volume (also not sure) or was it the flexibility that drove the final thinness?

NOTE: It's late here but I just ran across NASA NTRS Multilayer Insulation Material Guidelines Document ID: 19990047691, NASA/TP-1999-209263
I think someone else can dig into that and find a better answer.


I think part of the issue here is in the premise of the question; that 2 and 1 mil thick polymer films are "thin".
I looked at Johnson et al. (2017) Transmissivity Testing of Multilayer Insulation at Cryogenic Temperatures (also in researchgate) and it mentions metallized thin polymer films for thermal insulation made by https://sheldahl.com/ (note that JWST looms large on their main page. See also the Sheldahl RedBook (archived) which features the Echo II balloon "Manufactured by Sheldahl, 1961.
The scribid document Sheldahl RODUCT BULLETIN - Aluminum Coated (Two Sides) PET says:

Sheldahl’s family of Polyethylene Terephthalate (PET or polyester) films that are aluminized on bothsides can be used as first surface mirrors, and are often used in multi-layer insulation (MLI) blanketsin low temperature applications. These products provide low emittance and low solar absorptance. This product may be ordered with 0.25, 0.5, 1, 2, 3, or 5 mil thick PET that conforms to therequirements of MIL-I-631 and L-P-377. The aluminum coating is nominally 1000 Å thick, and the most common width is 48 inches (1.22 m).




Standard Item Number
Thickness mil (um)
Typical Weight(g/m^2)




146466
0.25 (6)
9


146463
0.5 (12.5)
17


146458
1.0 (25)
33


146460
2.0 (51)
71


146462
5.0 (127)
175



The polymer films in the JWST heat shield are given as 2 and 1 mil (1 mil = 0.001 inch ~ 25 microns) and these thicknesses are right in the middle of the thicknesses commercially available. They get a lot thinner (the thinnest is only 0.25 mil or 0.006 mm) and presumably those are still fairly easy to work with.
So I think that these thicknesses are not so thin as far as manageable commercial polymer films for insulation.
I would hazard a guess that they are not particularly delicate or prone to fall apart at the slightest breeze.
I can't prove that right now, but I think this is where the answer lies.

Thank you uhoh for providing detailed information on "thickness". It is such a relative term! My answer was based on decades of thermal management in the design of aircraft avionics. All my reference materials have been boxed up in storage for years or in my son's (also a mech engr) bookcase.

@BradV you are truly blessed! After storing my old stuff for almost two decades while I've been on the opposite side of the planet, my older and very-not-engineer sister downsized to a trailer in Florida and sold/tossed all of my stuff. I keep reminding myself that everything is impermanent to stay calm :-) In a "former life" I worked where there were cryogenic beam lines (superconducting magnets etc.) and we used "superinsulation". I don't know the specs, but it was very light and thin and flexible (we used many layers) and yet not delicate.

Thanks for your answer, it seems that my interpretation of how thick is 0.025 mm was incorrect. 0.025 mm is about thickness of a freezer bag!

From a "sun shielding" standpoint there is no need for the shades to be any thicker. They only need to be opaque to solar thermal radiation (light and heat... not nuclear decay radiation).
The first layer sunward "sees" the sun and blocks the sun's rays of light. The first layer blocks direct radiation but it then heats up itself. The first layer radiates this heat back sunward (which is mostly cold dark space) and backwards towards layer 2 with a portion of the heat bouncing out from between 1 and 2 and out into space. Layer 2 heats up a bit and radiates to layer 3 with a portion of that heat then bouncing out to space. And so on. The thickness of the layers is only important for the first layer so it can be opaque to light transmission. Each layer is incrementally cooler than the one sunward from it.
edit:  OP said "I can not understand why it has to be extremely thin." My answer approached from standpoint of functionally it does not need to be "thick" and so it is very thin. All the rest if it such as weight, furling and unfurling, etc is standard design give and take tradeoffs.

Maybe I have a wrong assumption that leads to this question, my assumption is that maintaining a very thin object is difficult and it might be easily damaged, thus creating a thicker one can be more resistant. Is this wrong?

@AmirrezaRiah the shield is not maintainable, but from damage (as well as thermal) point of view several thin layers are better on a weight basis than 1 thick one. When a micrometeorite hits the 1st layer, its impact energy spreads out in the gap between the 1st layer and the 2nd layer, so the gap results in reduced damage to the second layer. You can read more about that in discussions on inflatable space habitats (which use thicker layers than the JWST sunshield due to pressure and safety concerns.) There is no mechanical load on the JWST shield and thin layers are lighter and unfold easier.

@AmirrezaRiahi I've moved your comment back into your original question, along with more information from the link.

@AmirrezaRiahi Resistant to what? Thicker sheets wouldn't do anything in improve the strength and reliability of the shades. A micrometeor strike that punches through a 1 mil sheet is going to go right through a 10 mil sheet just as easily, so there's no gain to be had by increasing the weight of the payload. The only concern is getting it to orbit and deployed safely, and they clearly had that part figured out using the thinner sheets.

It was made as lightweight as possible
We can follow the development history through several research papers:

Evaluation of thin films for the Next-Generation Space Telescope (NGST) sunshield Eve M. Wooldridge, Charles E. Powers, 1998. Contains material comparisons and literature review of past space deployments.
Passive thermal control of the NGST Charles M. Perrygo, et al., 1998.
Effects of manufacturing and deployment on thin films for the NGST sunshade Eve Wooldridge, et al., 2001.
Technology Development for Large Deployable Sunshield to Achieve Cryogenic Environment Dean Waldie, Larry Gilman, 2004.

The initial weight design maximum in 1998 was 160 kg, including the support and deployment hardware. I didn't find the total mass of the sunshield design as built, but we can calculate that the film material itself weighs about 60 kg total. So the mass budget for the sunshield component is a tight fit, even if the whole telescope weighs 6500 kg.
The thickness requirements are summarized in [2]:

Film layer thicknesses will be in the range of 13 µm (0.5 mil) to 50 µm (2 mil). Minimizing mass requires using as thin a
film thickness as possible. From a handling and folding perspective, a film thickness of about 25 pm (1 mil) appears to be
optimum.

In the 2001 design [3], there are 6 layers with 0.5 and 1 mil thicknesses (as opposed to 5 layers with 1 and 2 mil thicknesses in the final design):

I didn't find a conclusive answer on what led to doubling the film thickness in the final design, but the design change appears to have occurred between 2002 and 2004. During that time frame there was research to micro-meteoroid tolerance and the effect of material wrinkles on the insulation performance.
The sun-facing layer sees the highest amount of radiation and dust exposure, so it makes sense that it is thicker.
In conclusion, it appears clear that there was a strong desire towards making the sunshield as lightweight as possible. This had to be balanced against the durability and insulation properties, which led to the 5-layer 1 and 2 mil design.

Also, in terms of engineering, the telescope has a fairly limited lifespan (it is just not going to be in operation for multiple decades the way Hubble has). There is no need to make the sun-shield survivable for 20 years if the propellant is going to run out after 10.

@SoronelHaetir that was indeed the nominal plan, but: The trajectory Ariane 5 placed James Webb on was accurate enough to minimize the amount of fuel the observatory needed for its trip to L2, allowing JWST to have enough fuel for around 20 years — 10 years more than originally expected — of scientific operations. found in this answer to How much fuel did JWST save due to an accurate launch, and how much will remain after L2 orbit?

@SoronelHaetir I agree, and it is also a direct tradeoff: make the sunshield heavier and there will be less propellant, so it will run out sooner. After all, there is only 300 kg of fuel on board, so the sunshield mass is not insignificant compared to that.
